# как конвертировать картинку RGB в HSV

Tags: c#, winforms, emgucv

почему picturebox2 черный.

```
Image<Hsv, byte> hsvimg=new Image<Hsv, byte>(pictureBox1.Width,pictureBox1.Height);
Image<Rgb, byte> img = new Image<Rgb, byte>((Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image);
CvInvoke.CvtColor(img,hsvimg,ColorConversion.Rgb2Hsv);
pictureBox2.Image = hsvimg.Bitmap;
```

Comment: Вот тут есть ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/637025/17025310

Comment: @Aarnihauta вы перепутали System.Drawing и Emgu.CV

Comment: К сожалению, `Bitmap` поддерживает только RGBA. Если вам нужно HSV, преобразуйте, обработайте и потом преобразуйте обратно, чтобы отдать в битмап. Вот список всех поддерживаемых режимов битмапа GDI+ https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat?view=net-5.0